# Range-v3 view::sliding(n) to return tuple (if n known at compile time)

Tags: c++, range-v3

```
std::vector v{1,2,3};

for (auto&& t : v | view::sliding(2)) {
    auto&& [first, second] = t;  // error - t is a range
}
```

is there a similar view in range-v3 that can return a tuple?

something like `sliding<2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is not exactly what you had in mind, but you can write something like:

```
template <typename T, size_t... I>
auto helper(T&& rng, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
   return std::make_tuple(rng[I]...);
}

int main() {
   std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5};
   for (auto&& t : v | ranges::view::sliding(3)) {
      auto&& [first, second, third] = helper(t, std::make_index_sequence<3>{});
      std::cout << first << ", " << second << ", " << third << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I don't know how to make *compile-time-sized* ranges.

Comment: `std::tie` seems better than `std::make_tuple`.

Comment: a `to_array`(`_ref`) seems more appropriate BTW.

Answer (score 4):

You could `zip` together `range` with `drop(range, i)` for all `i` in `[1,n)` ([**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1LVbY02AoQaTqDQh)):

```
std::vector v{1,2,3};

namespace view = ranges::view;
for (auto [first, second] : view::zip(v, view::drop(v, 1))) {
     std::cout << first << ", " << second << '\n';
}
```

This will quickly get ugly for larger `n`, and is almost certainly non-optimal, but far simpler than writing your own view adaptor.

Comment: For larger `n`, you can still use helper with `std::make_index_sequence` and `return ranges::view::zip(ranges::view::drop(v, Is)...);`.